# Two dimensional array pointer issue

Tags: arrays, pointers

I am trying to understand the pointer arithmetic wrt 2D arrays in C.

```
void pmanipulation(int arr[][5],int rows)
{
printf("arr=%d  arr+1=%d  *(arr)=%d *(arr+1)=%d\n",arr,arr+1,*(arr),*(arr+1));
}
```

In the small code snippet above, I observed that there is apparently no different in the value printed by arr+i and *(arr+i). Why is it so? I know that in C arr+i will give the base address of the ith row of the 2D matrix, but shouldn't *(arr+i) be printing element at that address?

Thanks

Comment: `*(arr+i)` is an array of 5 length. Can you print arrays with `printf()`? Yes, but only `char` arrays (= C-strings). You have an `int` array. And also `*(arr+i)` gives you the *adress* of the first element of ith row, while `arr+i` gives you the adress of the whole first row, which is the same as `*(arr+i)` with the subtle difference, that `*((arr+i)[n])` is stepping in `n*5` steps through elements and `(*(arr+i))[n]` only in `n` steps.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider this simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    int i,j;
    int a[3][5];
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<5;j++){
            a[i][j]=i*10+j;
        }
    }
    printf("a=%d a+1=%d *(a)=%d *(a+1)=%d\n", a, a+1, *(a), *(a+1));
}
```

When you compile this with gcc you get:

```
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:11:2: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int (*)[5]' [-Wformat]
test.c:11:2: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 3 has type 'int (*)[5]' [-Wformat]
test.c:11:2: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 4 has type 'int (*)' [-Wformat]
test.c:11:2: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 5 has type 'int (*)' [-Wformat]
```

You'll notice that `*(a+1)` is still a pointer.  Since this is a 2-dimensional array, you need to do a double de-reference in order to get the value `**(a+1)`.